# How to display each item in an array in React JS?

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I'm new to React and programing in general and I'm having trouble writing code that return each element in an array, in React JS.
the whole code is below:

```
import React from 'react'

const App = () => {
  const course = {
    name: 'Half Stack application development',
    parts: [
      {
        name: 'Fundamentals of React',
        exercises: 10
      },
      {
        name: 'Using props to pass data',
        exercises: 7
      },
      {
        name: 'State of a component',
        exercises: 14
      }
    ]
  }
  const Header = (props) => {
    return (
      <h1>{props.course.name}</h1>
    )
  }
  
  const Content = (props) => {
    const lisItem = props.course.parts.map((part =>
      <li>{props.course.parts.name}</li>
    ))
    return (
      <ul>{lisItem}</ul>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Header course={course}/>
      <Content course={course}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Right now it half-works: I can display 3 bullet points (match with numbers of `parts`) but cannot display the name of the part itself.

Also I would like to clarify the out put a wanted is the course's `name` and each `name` of the `parts` be displayed.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using `map` correctly. It should be like this:

```
const lisItem = props.course.parts.map((part) => <li>{part.name}</li>);
```

You were ignoring each `part` given to you by `map`. Check docs of `map`.

Also I see now you were defining the two components `Header` and `Content` **inside** the App component, that is not good practice (due to reconciliation), move their definition **outside** of `App`:

```
import React from "react";

const Header = (props) => {
  return <h1>{props.course.name}</h1>;
};

const Content = (props) => {
  const lisItem = props.course.parts.map((part) => <li>{part.name}</li>);
  return <ul>{lisItem}</ul>;
};

const App = () => {
  const course = {
    name: "Half Stack application development",
    parts: [
      {
        name: "Fundamentals of React",
        exercises: 10,
      },
      {
        name: "Using props to pass data",
        exercises: 7,
      },
      {
        name: "State of a component",
        exercises: 14,
      },
    ],
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Header course={course} />
      <Content course={course} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: thank you. i didn't understand the map function fully. and thank you for the advice constructing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.map( part => ...)` iterates `props.course.parts`, the part inside the map function is a single item of the list.

Check MDN for more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map